# The entrapment of Beastly Gerbil

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, grid-deduction

---

[Part 1: The disappearance of Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95086/the-disappearance-of-beastly-gerbil)
[Part 3: The escape of Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96700/the-escape-of-beastly-gerbil)

---

I've been trapped here for what feels like forever. This is all I've known. Darkness. The occasional flash of light, but then back to darkness, always, always .... back to the darkness. I'd give anything to escape this.

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\quad$ [image]

My senses are on fire. I'm... hyper-aware. I can feel everything, sense everything around me. It's torture. There's nothing to sense except the dark maze in which I am currently trapped. It feels like I'm being torn apart. I don't know who I am anymore...

But wait... I'm sensing... something. Something is happening... It's here, it's -

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\quad$ [image]

- crushing. I'm being thrown backwards. A stream of characters is flashing past me, blinding, deafening. I can sense every character as it passes, every pulse it emits as it crushes me from all sides.

> **ROT13O4YNAX1SBEY39R4526GGREC1H9G6AHZOREF2VATE5VQFB472YIR8NQQV6GVB2A9E1RNEEN4ATR82**

The same string, flying past over and over, every character inflicting unbearable pain. It's too much. It's crushing, it's....

gone.

Just like that I am left alone once again, alone in the darkness. I never thought I would be so relieved to be back in the dark. But wait. I'm sensing something again. It's coming. I can't, not again, anything but thi -

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\quad$ [image]

Another stream thundering past. I'm being pulled in all directions, it's literally tearing me apart. The same two grids, over and over and over. The stream continues...

[image][image]

It's endless, the pain, my senses burning, its - over, it's over finally, it's all over...

**I need help**. I don't even know where I am.

---

## Where is Beastly Gerbil trapped?

---

(Click on pictures provided to see them in better resolution)

[Number Grid in Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tvArHfQ8UQXjLTTqYe82h2c0VE04pWpv-t7pcMk-uaI/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Hint:

> 2 = 10

Comment: Could you give a text copy of the number grid?

Comment: @Deusovi, sure thing, if you open it in a new tab it's much, much clearer, but I'll add a google sheets link

Comment: I'm looking at the grid of numbers and keep thinking some of the cells look darker. Genuinely can't figure out if that's an optical illusion or not.

Comment: @Randal'Thor There are some darker ones, yes -- there's a plus sign of darker cells in the center of the number grid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start:

> The bold text says "ROT13", and then a lot more text. If we apply the rot13 cipher to the rest of the text, we get:
>
>  `B4LANK1FORL39E4526TTERP1U9T6NUMBERS2INGR5IDSO472LVE8ADDI6TIO2N9R1EARRA4NGE82`
>
>  The letters spell out a message: "Blank for letter, put numbers in grid; solve; addition; rearrange".

Next, we follow those instructions:

> The original message had 81 letters: exactly enough to fill a 9x9 grid. So, we put those numbers in the grid:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Hey, a 9x9 grid of numbers... looks like a Sudoku! And indeed it is:
>
>  [image]

The next instruction is

> "Addition". If we add the given numbers to the grid, we get another grid:
>
>  [image]
>
>  This has all the numbers from 1 to 81 once.

So, the last instruction says

> "Rearrange": this tells us how to rearrange the black/white/gray grid on the right. Using the numbers from 1-81 to fill in another grid (cell 1 goes in the top left, cell 2 goes right of that, etc) gives an image with a nice gray border:
>
>  [image]

The last step was found by Jens:

> Reading each row as binary, we get numbers 8, 74, 7, 5, 88, 53, 7.
>
>  Translating these numbers to chemical elements gives O, W, N, B, Ra, I, N, which spells **OWN BRAIN**.

Comment: Wow! That was unbelievably quick! You're on the right track, keep thinking :)

Comment: @Beastly Unbelievably? This is Deus we're talking about ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor true lol, and hes so close to the final answer too :)

Comment: Looking from left side of the image we get rot13(P cyhf), not sure what does it mean, maybe combining it to the rests of the left part of the image?

Comment: Deusovi's gonna be kicking himself after solving another recent puzzle lol

Comment: As it's been over a day, I've added a small hint, hopefully the final bit can be solved now

Comment: @Beastly Regarding the kicking, I see what you mean! :) Sometimes one's brain works in mysterious ways.

Comment: @Jens if you have the answer you can always post another partial!!! I’ll probably give deusovi the tick as he’s got to where he has, but if you’ve worked it out you definitely deserve the credit!!!

Comment: Hey deusovi, I can award the tick if you add in a final answer, I want to award it to you as you solved the majority of this (and very quickly!), but if you feel like it should go to Jens, I can award it to him? Although I know he wants you to get it :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Added!

Comment: @Deusovi well deserved tick!! Although might want to change the title of your answer as it’s no longer partial :)

Comment: I think the [cipher] tag should have been included.

Answer (score 5):

Beastly Gerbil is trapped in his

> **OWN BRAIN**

We get this answer by

> converting the 7 lines in the final square (found by Deusovi) into binary, with white squares as 0 and black squares as 1. This gives (from the top) 8, 74, 7, 5, 88, 53, 7. Taking these as atomic numbers we find that their element symbols are O, W, N, B, Ra, I, N, which becomes **OWN BRAIN**!

Please give Deusovi the tick as he did the majority of the work!

Comment: Congrats!!! Next up, the finale - the escape of beastly gerbil :P the best thing about this is deusovi not only tried 7 bit binary (presumably only tried converting to ASCII)  he solved another puzzle a couple of hours ago where the answer was hidden using chemical elements lol. Well done on the final answer!!

Comment: I know about that other puzzle because that puzzle was mine! :)

Comment: oh lol, no wonder you saw the answer here then! :P