# The escape of Beastly Gerbil

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual, story

#### The finale of a three part series:

[Part 1 - The disappearance of Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95086/the-disappearance-of-beastly-gerbil)
[Part 2 - The entrapment of Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96422/the-entrapment-of-beastly-gerbil)

---

I have a lot to think about... firstly I disappeared for two years, and now it turns out I was trapped in my own brain...

Well I'm out now and I'm back. I don't really recall how I escaped to be honest, all I know is that I did. But surely there was something that I managed to focus on to get me out...

Wait... where am I? I don't recognise any of my surroundings... am I... day dreaming?

In front of me is a bus stop, but it looks... odd. Like it's not supposed to be there. I'm going to take a closer look...

The wall in front of me seems to be some advert for 'PSE Buses'...

[image: ![enter image description here]

The logo for the company looks weirdly familiar, although I don’t know what the text is referring to. Every 7 what... why is it free?

$\quad$    [image]

The bus routes don't seem to have a map, they're just random lines, maybe the map is missing... (click for a better resolution image)

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\quad$ [image]

I take a look at the bus time. It looks like gibberish but I [made a copy of it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AxaaD7A9AjfwH7PdKYX4jrPryqATPtiVaSRG-N-Fk6U/edit?usp=sharing) to see if it might mean something, and wrote out the text. Surely this means *something*, it certainly looks like some of it is encrypted, what could the key be...

```
FROM         TO           Here as bus, train or taxi
-wl.titbcpj  uq.vjtaftn   Likely bus or train
xq.pnzjjrl   c.rvhujjp    Could be any who knows
-lx.ovjbhdn  fzm.mmbbill  Probably bus if it will stop
wn.qmtggth   ulv.hcjkset  Actually could be a plane
-ks.gcjjqeu  jqf.xdinmzq  For certain bus as thats the topic
qe.zfdpfc    -pq.gtiipnz  Obviously bus if it will halt
-kr.gtehtec  -mv.lvjjtlx  However this could be a taxi next
vq.bmtipwx   xx.evetqmg   Really sure it’s a bus just watch
lm.rwtipmk   qz.mmibwwm   Bus please
iw.itsgcsf   jq.eltmjwf   Quite sure its all
qz.hmhjdat   af.lxbsped   Uncertain need more info
ga.yketzrx   id.prtipvx   Yeah it’s a bus thats coming
aa.teebdiw   wf.ededlvx   Probably bus too
```

Finally there is the bus info, I hoped it could've helped me understand everything but it's just as confusing. I feel like it’s hiding something though...

> Hello, if you are in here, probably stopped to read a snippet, a stop is right there! Lets kindly help here, you can stop. Come, we have loads of options waiting. Probably though, as this is muddled up, you’re somewhat addled. Fear not in here! Only some dare to stop. You shall have a bus, be fast ok? Hurry on please, all buses, aka who steers, very fast drive on. Rest now. Be placid. I assume from this that you see what comes soon. Jog on, move! For buses drive and only pause if asked.
>
> @54.3692178,-1.6505385,10z

---

I'm incredibly confused... but I feel like this is meant to tell me what helped me escape.

## Can you help me make sense of all of this?

---

I will add one hint every 24 hours since posting...

Hint 1:

> Some has already been solved in the comments. Jens wrote:
>
> 'I took every 7th letter of the bus info which gave me "FIRST S ARE KEY TWO PARTS MUST FIND THE FULL KEY IS PARTS COMBINED"'
>
> And Kralc wrote:
>
> 'The last line of the bus info looks like a Google Maps location link? - google.com/maps/@54.3692178,-1.6505385,10z'
>
> Both of these are correct. The hint is that I could have added 'sentence' before the first line of the riddle.

Hint 2:

> It seems that the 'FROM' 'TO' text is encrypted with a vigenere cipher. Can you decrypt it?

Comment: Complete sidenote, making [letters from the site logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vL0e.png) looks really cool...

Comment: Seems like you're very *busy*.

Comment: @Jens it would seem you’re applying it in the wrong place, every single step here you’ll know where you get it. Out of interest where have you been trying it?

Comment: I took rot13(rirel 7gu yrggre bs gur ohf vasb juvpu tnir zr "SVEFG F NER XRL GJB CNEGF ZHFG SVAQ GUR SHYY XRL VF CNEGF PBZOVARQ")

Comment: @Jens your second comment is correct. That’s a possible first step here, also the first word is 6 letters, so you know how it’s punctuated

Comment: The last line of the bus info looks like rot13(n Tbbtyr Zncf ybpngvba yvax? - tbbtyr.pbz/zncf/@54.3692178,-1.6505385,10m)

Comment: @Kralc you would be correct

Comment: When you say "riddle" in Hint 1, do you mean the bus info?

Comment: For me the problem is not so much the key (several possibilities), it's what encryption method was used. I see the clue in the 2 lines beneath the "Every 7!!", but surely that's for later?

Comment: @Jens yes the bus info. I can say there is no hint here that says the type of cipher, but the cipher is probably the most common one on the site. And yes those two are for later :)

Comment: @Jens as the latest hint says, the cipher is a vigenere cipher

Comment: I know, but I tried that even before your hint and got nowhere. My expectation was to get rot13(yrggref va gur enatr N gb W) but that didn't happen. Guess I'll wait for your next hint. :)

Comment: @Jens I'm willing to be quite open with hints lol as I really didn't think this would take that long. What keys have you used/ciphertext? I might have made something not very obvious or there might be a small error somewhere. I've gone through and all the reproduced results where the ones I expected tho :)

Comment: As keys I've tried the rot13(svefg jbeq bs rnpu ohf vasb fragrapr naq nyfb gur svefg jbeq bs rnpu ohf fpurqhyr fragrapr).

Comment: Lol sorry @Randal'Thor :P

Comment: @Jens bold of you to assume the riddle refers to words ;) 'Sentence firsts' is very literal lol

Comment: Well, that hint gave me 13 letters that make sense, but after that it's gibberish. I'm guessing I only have the first part of the key. Maybe I should start a partial answer as the puzzle will otherwise be worked out entirely in comments.

Comment: @Jens probably a good idea, plus you deserve a lot of credit for how far you’ve got!! And also ‘two parts must find’ :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way Beastly Gerbil escaped was by focusing on

> **PUZZLES**!

If we apply the "Every 7" clue to the

> Bus info, by taking every 7th letter, we get the message "FIRSTS ARE KEY. TWO PARTS MUST FIND. THE FULL KEY IS PARTS COMBINED".

Now, we know that the From/To parts of the bus schedule are encrypted

> So, the KEY in the message above presumably refers to the encryption key. Notice that there are 13 entries in the bus schedule and *also* 13 sentences in the bus info. I initially thought the FIRSTS referred to the first *word* in the bus info sentences, but hints by OP indicated that it was in fact the first *letter* that was relevant.

So

> Taking the first letter of each of the bus info sentences gives HLCPFOYHRBIJF. If we now use this as the key in a Vigenere cipher for the first entry in the From/To columns (which is *-wl.titbcpj  uq.vjtaftn*), we get **"-pa.rtoneis ti.mempdei"**. The first 13 letters here give "PART ONE IS TIME".

And (thank you @Kralcl!)

> If we take the first letters of the bus schedule sentences *including the title*  we get HLCPAFOHRBQUYP. Applying this as a new key to the first entry, gives **"-pa.rttwois ta.bletury"**, i.e. "PART TWO IS TABLE". Combining part one and part two gives **TIMETABLE**.

Using this as a new key

> on all entries in the From/To columns gives:
>
>  -dd.heabbef bi.jfaaeij
>  ei.djgjigh j.jjdbjie
>  -he.gjfihcc bge.aiibhah
>  df.eiagfid bdj.djjjhaa
>  -cg.cjjifab beb.edhcigi
>  ea.gfcebj -he.caihejg
>  -cf.caegiaj -ej.hcjiihe
>  ne.xtthese pl.acesfin
>  da.ndtheir in.itialst
>  ak.easfrom be.astlysm
>  in.dthiswa st.hebreak
>  yo.uresone ar.lythere
>  so.pleased ot.akecare

The bottom six entries give the message

> NEXT THESE PLACES FIND AND THEIR INITIALS TAKE AS FROM BEASTLYS MIND THIS WAS THE BREAK YOU'RE SO NEARLY THERE SO PLEASE DO TAKE CARE.

So

> We need to convert the top seven entries into coordinates, i.e. numbers. Notice that the entries only have letters in the interval A to J. The clue to conversion is the two sentences under the "Every 7!!" line. They start with "A zero..." and "Be one...", which suggests using A = 0, B = 1, etc for the conversion.

If we do this we get

> -33.7401145 18.9500489
>  48.3969867 9.9931984
>  -74.6958722 164.0881707
>  35.4806583 139.3999700
>  -26.2998501 141.4372868
>  40.652419 -74.2087496
>  -25.2046809 -49.7298874

Looking these up using Google Maps/Earth we find

> Paarl Rock, South Africa
>  Ulm, Germany
>  Zucchelli Station, Antarctica
>  Zama Station, Japan
>  Lake Yamma Yamma, Australia
>  Elizabeth, USA
>  Sete Saltos, Brazil

Finally,

> Taking the first letters of each location spells **PUZZLES**!

*Postscript*

> The bus route diagram and the coordinates at the bottom of the bus info was another clue (not used by me). If the coordinates are entered into Google Maps and the route lines are overlayed, we get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZFf.png). Following the lines in the rainbow order gives "LATLONG", a hint to look for coordinates.
>
>  There was also an easter egg in the bus schedule sentences. The last letters of each sentence gives "inspect the logo", presumably a reference to the final answer.

Comment: Wow you’re so close to the next part :P but surely if the other key gives ‘part two’ then the key will also have to start with HLCP... there’s your hint for today :)

Comment: rot13(Gur svefg yrggref bs gur terra pbyhza tvir UYPCNSBUEODHLC -> "cneg gjb vf gnoyr"

Eha gur pvcure ntnva (ba gur jubyr oybpx bs pvcuregrkg) jvgu "GVZRGNOYR" tvirf "arkg gurfr cynprf svaq naq gurve vavgvnyf gnxr nf sebz ornfgylf zvaq guvf jnf gur oernx lbher fb arneyl gurer fb cyrnfr qb gnxr pner" ng gur raq)

Comment: Have you tried overlaying your coords and the route map diagram?

Comment: @Stiv Only by eye by looking at a world map. Didn't seem to fit. Not sure how to try it electronically.

Comment: @Jens this is the answer!! Congrats! I'll give you the rest as it may be difficult to reach and is non-essential to the rest. If you go to https://www.google.com/maps/@54.3692178,-1.6505385,10z and overlay the bus routes you get the following:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZFf.png  and taking the letters from the rainbow (ROYGBIV) gives 'LATLONG' - it's not huge on the impact of the puzzle it was just a bonus :) The other bonus is the last letters of the bus info say 'inspect the logo'. If you want to edit those in I can give you the check! :)

Comment: @Jens also just seen the error for the S in puzzles. It should be -25..... not 25. I'll edit the question, it should give you somewhere in brazil so there is one letter from every continent :)

Comment: ^ Apparently it already is -25, there's the error :)

Comment: @Beastly Error fixed. :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Just FYI, I think the Google Maps clue may be screen resolution/DPI dependant; they don't line up (without resizing) on my screen. It didn't stop the solution being found, though!

Comment: @Kralc I was worried that might be the case so I only made it an Easter egg :))